# Filter array of object inside array of object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter this json.

here is the json

```
const json = {
  address: "fdqn",
  pDet: [
    {
      pNam: "pnam1",
      pMem: [
        {
          mIP: "1234",  // search this string '1234'
          gp: "gp1"
        }, {
          mIP: "567", 
          gp: "gp2"
        }, {
          mIP: "890", 
          gp: "gp3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      pNam: "pnam1",
      pMem: [
        {
          mIP: "4567", 
          gp: "gp5"
        }, {
          mIP: "5674", 
          gp: "gp7"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to filter with **mIP = "1234"** and the final output should be.

```
const json = {
    address: "fdqn",
    pDet: [
      {
        pNam: "pnam1",
        pMem: [
          {
            mIP: "1234", 
            gp: "gp1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

i tried with filter and some but seems i need to iterate inside the filter.
any input will be appreciated

Comment: Your 'json' is not JSON. It's a JavaScript object. If you tried to solve this with code, you should include the code so someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizing `flatMap` to emulate the behavior of `filter_map` in [other languages](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map), we could achieve the result like this:

```js
const json = {address:"fdqn",pDet:[{pNam:"pnam1",pMem:[{mIP:"1234",gp:"gp1"},{mIP:"567",gp:"gp2"},{mIP:"890",gp:"gp3"}]},{pNam:"pnam1",pMem:[{mIP:"4567",gp:"gp5"},{mIP:"5674",gp:"gp7"}]}]};

const search = "1234";

const result = {
    address: json.address,
    // check if there is any match in this pMem
    pDet: json.pDet.flatMap(({ pMem }) => pMem.some(({ mIP }) => mIP === search)
        ? [pMem.filter(({ mIP }) => mIP === search)] // if there is, return filtered array
        : [] // otherwise, return nothing
    ),
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Although I like this overall (and upvoted), note that because the `filter` callback and the `map` callback both iterated through the input, and some of the advantages of `filterMap` are missing.  I noticed this when I tried the problem with my simple, `const filterMap = (f, m) => (xs) => xs .flatMap (x => f (x) ? [m (x)] : [])`.  I will try to write an answer with an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array.reduce()` and `array.filter()` like this.

```js
const json = { address: "fdqn", pDet: [{ pNam: "pnam1", pMem: [{ mIP: "1234", gp: "gp1" }, { mIP: "567", gp: "gp2" }, { mIP: "890", gp: "gp3" }] }, { pNam: "pnam1", pMem: [{ mIP: "4567", gp: "gp5" }, { mIP: "5674", gp: "gp7" }] } ] }

const newJSON = {
    address: json.address,
    pDet: json.pDet.reduce((newArr, obj) => {
        const pMem = obj.pMem.filter(obj2 => obj2.mIP === '1234')
        if (pMem.length) newArr.push({
            pNam: obj.pNam,
            pMem
        })
        return newArr
    }, [])
}

console.log(newJSON)
```

In a function it could look like this:

```js
const json = { address: "fdqn", pDet: [{ pNam: "pnam1", pMem: [{ mIP: "1234", gp: "gp1" }, { mIP: "567", gp: "gp2" }, { mIP: "890", gp: "gp3" }] }, { pNam: "pnam1", pMem: [{ mIP: "4567", gp: "gp5" }, { mIP: "5674", gp: "gp7" }] } ] }

function filterArray(jsonObj, searchStr) {
    return {
        address: json.address,
        pDet: json.pDet.reduce((newArr, obj) => {
            const pMem = obj.pMem.filter(obj2 => obj2.mIP === search)
            if (pMem.length) newArr.push({
                pNam: obj.pNam,
                pMem
            })
            return newArr
        }, [])
    }
}

const newJSON = filterArray(json, '1234')

console.log( newJSON )
```

Comment: See my answer for a similar, but somewhat more generic approach.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the technique in the answer from [@caTS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/cats), although a little more generic, I used a `filterMap`.  In my case, I grabbed a reusable function I have handy.  It looks like this:

```js
const filterMap = (f, m) => (xs) => xs .flatMap (x => f (x) ? [m (x)] : [])

const searchMIP = ({pDet, ...rest}, query) => ({
  ...rest,
  pDet: filterMap (
    ({pMem}) => pMem .some (({mIP}) => mIP == query),
    ({pMem, ...rest}) => ({...rest, pMem: pMem .filter (({mIP}) => mIP == query)})
  ) (pDet)
})

const obj = {address: "fdqn", pDet: [{pNam: "pnam1", pMem: [{mIP: "1234", gp: "gp1"}, {mIP: "567", gp: "gp2"}, {mIP: "890", gp: "gp3"}]}, {pNam: "pnam1", pMem: [{mIP: "4567", gp: "gp5"}, {mIP: "5674", gp: "gp7"}]}]}

console .log (searchMIP (obj, '1234'))
```

But I wasn't really happy with that, as one of the usual advantages of `filterMap` is that it only scans the list once.  But here, we do it in the *filter* section, using `some` and again in the *map* section using `filter`.

So here's a slightly different approach, still using `flatMap` to do something similar, but filtering only once and using the `length` of the result to decide whether we're keeping the object at all:

```js
const searchMIP = ({pDet, ...rest}, query) => ({
  ...rest,
  pDet: pDet .flatMap (
    ({pMem, kids = pMem .filter (({mIP}) => mIP == query), ...rest}) => kids .length ? [({
      ...rest, 
      pMem: pMem .filter (({mIP}) => mIP == query)
    })] : [] 
  )
})

const obj = {address: "fdqn", pDet: [{pNam: "pnam1", pMem: [{mIP: "1234", gp: "gp1"}, {mIP: "567", gp: "gp2"}, {mIP: "890", gp: "gp3"}]}, {pNam: "pnam1", pMem: [{mIP: "4567", gp: "gp5"}, {mIP: "5674", gp: "gp7"}]}]}

console .log (searchMIP (obj, '1234'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This is more similar to the answer from user [@Ludolfyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11472399/ludolfyn), but without the mutable accumulator, and again, slightly more generic.